# Granting Administrator Rights During Run-Time

Tags: c#, vb.net, security, uac, elevated-privileges

I'm working on a project which requires **Administrator rights** after clicking a button.
currently using **C#** and **VB.NET**. Your answer language is up to you, but better if it is in one of them. :)

I already tried the following:

- **"runas" verb with a new process** but the problem is that it re-starts the application which means losing all current progress and variable values.
- **editing manifest file**, but I *"don't want to force"* the user to run the application as admin.

As previously said, Administrator Right required only when clicking on a button. If it never been clicked then No rights needed!

So, is there anyway to **grant Administrator rights during run-time** via UAC, for instance. Without restarting the application.

I've searched the web and all I got was the methods already mentioned above :)

**NOTE:** I found something similar to what I need in **Microsoft Security Essential** where it's able to grant Administrator rights without starting a new instance of the application.

[image: MSE can do it!]
**Description:** When running **MSE**, by default, you'll find in **History tab** that **first** radio box is chosen.
changing this to any other option and granting the right **won't** restart application therefore, **maintaining** current **state**.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: afaik: You can not elevate a running process. If you have an app that asks for admin rights "sometimes" and then does something without closing, that app usually simply spawns a new process (to do a specific task) with admin rights in the background.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to tell if an app started a **new process** or temporarily **elevated** it self.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to elevate during the lifetime of a process. Whether or not your process runs elevated is decided at process startup time.

> I found something similar to what I need in Microsoft Security Essential where it's able to grant Administrator rights without starting a new instance of the application.

No, MSE will be performing the elevated tasks in a separate process.

You don't need to close the existing process and start a new one. What you are expected to do is to use a separate process to perform just the tasks that require elevation. That separate process does not need to show any UI. The elevated process can remain hidden and communicate with the process that displays the UI. The cleanest way to achieve this is to put the elevated tasks inside an out-of-process COM server and to use `CoCreateInstanceAsAdmin`.

Comment: +1 Well, that's interesting; could it possibly mean that there is a way for a non-elevated app to communicate with MSE and make it display those admin settings? Anyway, most likely these settings will be persisted through an elevated process again anyway, even if you somehow manage to make it show them.

Comment: @Groo I don't understand the question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't examine the OP's example thoroughly enough. I thought he was saying that MSE asks for elevated rights, and then shows an additional tab or something based on an action of a hidden elevated process. In other words, the part where *elevated process can remain hidden and communicate with the [non-elevated] process that displays the UI* made me think that the functionality requiring privileges may actually exist within the *non-elevated* process, and is merely being enabled by a background process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for the hint! I found a nice article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679687%28VS.85%29.aspx) but for C++ :)